# how to directly add ENUM in Mybatis IN query ,with no params

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, mybatis-sql

i directly have to check ENUM in where condition ,

```
 <if test="params.fileTypes != null and !params.fileTypes.isEmpty()">
        AND
        RTRIM(INTH.IF_FILETYPE) IN
        <foreach item="item" index="index"
            collection="params.fileTypes" open="(" separator="," close=")">
            #{item}
        </foreach>
   </if>
   <if test="params.fileTypes.isEmpty()">
        AND
        RTRIM(IF_FILETYPE) IN (#{@com.xyz.wealth.appconfiguration.domain.FileType})
   </if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `com.xyz.wealth.appconfiguration.domain.FileType` is the enum you are referring to and it has two values. e.g.

```java
public enum FileType {
  DOCUMENT,
  IMAGE
}
```

The following MyBatis statement ...

```xml
RTRIM(IF_FILETYPE) IN (
<foreach item="x" separator=","
    collection="@om.xyz.wealth.appconfiguration.domain.FileType@values()">
  #{x}
</foreach>
)
```

... is translated into the SQL below and the enum values `DOCUMENT` and `IMAGE` are bound to the placeholders as string respectively.

```
RTRIM(IF_FILETYPE) IN (?, ?)
```